# Set log file name with date

Tags: java, log4j2, log4j

I have this Log4J configuration which writes log messages.

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();  // Basic configuration for Log4J 1.x

        ConsoleAppender console = new ConsoleAppender(); //create appender
        //configure the appender
        String PATTERN = "%d [%p|%c|%C{1}] %m%n";
        console.setLayout(new PatternLayout(PATTERN));
        console.setThreshold(Level.FATAL);
        console.activateOptions();
        //add appender to any Logger (here is root)
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(console);

        DailyRollingFileAppender fa = new DailyRollingFileAppender();
        fa.setName("FileLogger");
        fa.setFile("log" + File.separator + "messages.log");
        fa.setDatePattern("'.'yyyy-MM-dd");
        fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
        fa.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
        fa.setAppend(true);
        fa.activateOptions();

        //add appender to any Logger (here is root)
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(fa); //repeat with all other desired appenders
```

I have a mistake into the code configuration. I want to write new log file every day with date as name. Now I get only the name messages.log without the date. Can you help me to fix this issue?

Comment: I think the code is fine. You won't be able to test it until midnight (or unless you change the time on your system). According to the documentation, "At midnight, on March 8th, 2002, /foo/bar.log will be copied to /foo/bar.log.2002-03-08."

Comment: As aquaraga said, DailyRollingFileAppender makes the change in filename when it receives a logging even meeting the requirement. i.e when the date is new and the old log file name needs to be added with its date. Did you test the code changing the time to Midnight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to worry, your code is fine :)

The **current** log file is named `messages.log`.

Only when the next file starts, this name is changed.

From [javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html#setDatePattern%28java.lang.String%29):

> For example, if the File option is set to /foo/bar.log and the
>   DatePattern set to '.'yyyy-MM-dd, on 2001-02-16 at midnight, the
>   logging file /foo/bar.log will be copied to /foo/bar.log.2001-02-16
>   and logging for 2001-02-17 will continue in /foo/bar.log until it
>   rolls over the next day

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
String PATTERN = "%d{DATE} [%p|%c|%C{1}] %m%n";
```

Comment: There is no relation with it's LOGGING PATTERN

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this feature: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-239 (»RollingFileAppender should support logging directly to the file referenced in the filePattern«)